# Why is my code returning all records when I am trying to subset inside for loop - R?

Tags: dataset

```
for (i in 1:length(data$name)){
```

if (!is.na(data$years[i]) >= 34 & !is.na(data$gender[i]) == "male" & !is.na(data$classification[i]) == "mid"){
print(data$name)
}
}

Comment: Are you a SAS programmer?  R doesn't work like this.  I will try to help you.

Comment: `is.na(...)` returns `TRUE/FALSE`, so `!is.na(data$classification[i]) == "mid"` will never be TRUE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few problems in your code. I am assuming this is a class exercise or similar, so I'll add a bit extra detail to illustrate where you've missed a step.

First of all you loop works fine, but your if condition is not completely correct.

```
!is.na(data$years[i]) >= 34
```

All of your conditions look (somewhat) like this. The idea is obvious, you want to "check that `data$years[i]` is not null, and above 34". But in R (and most languages) you have to check these seperately.

```
!is.na(data$years[i]) && data$years[i] >= 34
```

Similar for the rest of your conditions.

Next your print statement is printing out everything, because this is what you're asking it to:

```
print(data$name)
```

is "ignorant" of anything else you've done up till now. It seems you want to print the specific record, eg:

```
print(data$name[i])
```

And this is the way to go about it.

Now R has a thing called "vectorization", so we could wrap this entire loop up in one go:

```
data$name[!is.na(data$years) & !is.na(data$gender) & !is.na(data$classification) & data$year > 34 & data$gender == "male" & data$classification == "mid"]
```

But I am assuming that is not part of your current exercise. Note the slight (but important) difference that for vectorized (eg. more than 1) condition I use single `&` but for single conditions I use 2 `&&`. The latter is optimized to be "lazy" for single inputs (thus faster).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation!

Comment: My pleasure. :-) Remember to mark an answer as "the answer". It helps increase the questions visibility for others who have similar questions in the future, and rewards the user of the marked answer with 15 points, keeping the ones answering question here incentivized to use their spare time helping others out. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try `subset` + `complete.cases` like below

```
subset(
  data,
  years >= 34 & gender == "male" & classification == "mid" & complete.cases(data[c("years", "gender", "classification")])
)$name
```